# How can I delete particular image in the database and folder inside one action in PHP?

Tags: php, html

I have a table in the database called `products`. The table contains `id` which is the primary key `A_I property`, `name`, and `price`.

The table contents are displayed on the home page of my site. The same site has an admin panel that manages the stock, one of them being deleting particular products from the table as well as from the home page.

The problem is when the product is deleted its image still remains in the folder I don't want that to happen.

I have made research and found about the unlink function that deletes a $file but I can't figure out how to use it in my case. How can I relate/link a particular image to its id so that the unlink method will know which image to delete from the folder? Somebody help, please.

Here is my code that displays the products to home page:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
<?php while($product=$result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-11 mx-auto my-3">
  <h4><?= $product['product_name']; ?></h4>
     <a class="test-popup-link" href="<?= $product['product_image']; ?>">
       <img src="<?= $product['product_image']; ?>" class="img-fluid rounded mx-auto d-block" alt="Hp 840" id="images">
      </a>
 
  <p class="list-price text-danger">List Price <s>Ksh. <?= $product['list_price']; ?></s></p>
  <p class="price">Our Price: Ksh. <?= $product['our_price']; ?></p>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" 
  data-target="#<?= $id; ?>">Details</button>
</div>
<?php } ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What sort of file names do the images have?  How does the application know which image to display for a particular product?

Comment: file names are the original names of the images . jpg, .png, ets.  I used the while loop to display all products from the table.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67877876/edit) to show us the code that displays products.

Comment: @kmoser done with editing. Please revisit.

Comment: @kmoser is right. You don't need the above code to delete from folder. But selecting from the database and the delete via the unlink function

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? The given code does not show any details about how you handle the deletion of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the name contains the file extension...

```
<?php unlink("images/{$product['product_image_name']}"); ?>
```

if the name does not contain the file extension, then add it..

```
<?php unlink("images/{$product['product_image_name']}.jpg"); ?>
```

or if the file extension is in another field

```
<?php unlink("images/{$product['product_image_name'] . $product['product_image_extension']}"); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @blackmambo. I got the concept right

Answer (score 1):

> How can I relate/link a particular image to its id so that unlink method will know which image to delete from the folder?

Exactly the same way you already know how to display the image:

```
<img src="<?= $product['product_image']; ?>"
```

The row in the database must already contain the file name for that to work, so before deleting the row, you would write something like this to find the image to delete:

```
Select product_image From products Where id = ?
```